# odd append behaviour

Tags: c, file, append

If I have a file containing

```
manual
/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth

/lib/plymouth/themes/spinfinity/spinfinity.plymouth
10
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
100
```

and then I open it in `a` mode, then do

```
fprintf(f, "/el/derpito.plymouth\n100\n");
```

why is the file now containing this?

```
manual
/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth

/lib/plymouth/themes/spinfinity/spinfinity.plymouth
10
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
100

/el/derpito.plymouth
100
```

I'd expect the file to be this instead:

```
manual
/lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth

/lib/plymouth/themes/spinfinity/spinfinity.plymouth
10
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
100
/el/derpito.plymouth
100
```

Comment: Try Notepad++ or some other good editor which can show you the whitespace. There seems to be an extra \n at the end of the original file.

Comment: Oddly, no. I have settled with opening the file in `r`, and another in `w`, and manually copying lines until the point where I need to add more lines. Then I delete the first file and rename the new one to the old one's name. This obviously isn't elegant, but it's the best solution I've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a lonely \n or \cr stuck at the end of the file before you make the write. I wuld open it with a hex editor and see.

Comment: The file is meant to end in one newline. If I open in append mode, then write something (that doesn't start with a newline), I expect it to be appended directly after the newline provided by the file, not with another newline.

Comment: @Delan have you examined the file with a hex or other editor before and after the writes to display what is _actually_ happening and not what you think _should_ be happening?

Comment: Yes. The file ends in `100\n`, and I intend to append `/el/derpito.plymouth\n100\n`, but what is really being appended is `\n/el/derpito.plymouth\n100`. It's like the ending newline I appended moved to the start of the new data.

Comment: @Delan I had some time after work to look at this, and I don't know what to tell you other than you haven't examined it closely enough and you actually have an extra newline in there. When I open it in a hex editor, if I have two trailing 0x0A's ('\n') at the end, then I get the behavior you are talking about. When I make sure that only one 0x0A, then I get your "desired" output. You did not open the file with a hex editor, obviously. Try using vi, if you don't have one. http://www.linuxinstead.com/blog/2009/04/21/using-vi-as-a-hex-editor/. I am interested to hear the results.

Answer (score 0):

my first guess would be that the last character of your file (before the appending) is a newline-character, after which append appends the new line.

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comments to San Jacinto's answer, the file initially ends in *one* newline after `100`, but my append is acting as if there were two.